# Using value inside a column in where clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table where rules can be configured. Eg:

```
Rule_ID Rule_Condition
1       cust_no=10 and cust_name='John'
2       cust_no=20 or cust_name='Alex'
3       cust_no=40
```

And another table with the actual data

```
 Cust_No Cust_Name
 10      John
 10      Rob
 20      Dave
 20      Alex
 30      Steve
```

What is the simplest way to join these two and get the following output?

```
Rule_Id Cust_No Cust_Name
1       10      John
2       20      Dave
2       20      Alex
```

Appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can't `"JOIN"` these 2 tables because there's no relation between them. You can iterate through the `Rules` table in a `dynamic SQL` to create the `Where` clause with the `Rule Condition`.

Comment: Are there more possibilities of rules?  You will have to list everything for someone to give you an accurate answer. This will be hellish to solve.

Comment: The only option that came into my mind was using dynamic SQL. Wanted to know if there was a better way that I did not know of.

Comment: All the possibilities for the rules are limited to the columns in actual data, meaning all rule conditions will be a valid where clause for the actual data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dynamic SQL:

Here is an example which I think will help you a lot:

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(256), @Table sysname;

SET @SQL='SELECT * FROM'; SET @Table = 'Production.Product'

SET @SQL = @SQL+' '+@Table

PRINT @SQL     -- for debugging dynamic SQL prior to execution of generated static code

EXEC (@SQL)    -- Microsoft dynamic SQL execution - SQL Server 2005 execute dynamic SQL
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have a dynamic SQL option in hand; but was curious if there was a more straight forward way as the rule condition is a valid where clause for actual data.